# how to avoid showing the box if javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using javascript to hide boxes on my site, then when a user clicks in a text area this particular box will be shown. however if the user ,for whatever reason , is viewing my site offline or without javascript enabled, or even sometimes when the page is slow at loading, these boxes which are supposed to be hidden by javascript can be seen, and I was wondering if I can use css or something else to hide box by default unless called for by javascript?

I am really new to javascript and would appreciate it if someone could show me what I would need to do. thanks.

```
<script>
           $(function() {
            $(".search_prompt").hide();
            var focusin_flag = false,
                focusout_flag = false;
            $("#text").focusin(function() {
                if (!focusin_flag) {
                    $(".search_prompt").show();
                    focusin_flag = true;
                }
            }).focusout(function () {
                if (!focusout_flag ) {
                    $(".search_prompt").hide();
                    focusout_flag = true;
                } 
                function timeout_init() {
        setTimeout('search_prompt()', 2000);

                }

            });
        });  

        </script>
```

Comment: Hmm, if there is no javascript enabled, you can't call some javascript right ?

Answer (score 1):

in your css set `.search_prompt` **display** as `none`

```
.search_prompt
{
    display:none;
}
```

this way , by default the box is hidden , then if javascript is enabled , you can display it when required .

Comment: If JS is unavailable, there's no way to reveal the content unless the user also turns off CSS.

Comment: @cimmanon : ?! he wants boxes to be hidden until they are visible by javascript .the situation "how to display boxes if javascript is not available" is not asked in the question .

Answer (score 1):

I think the best method is to add the same class to the all the boxes you want hidden if JS is disabled.

```
<div class="xyz"> ... </div>
```

Add a class to your body that will be removed via js.

```
<body class="no-js"> ... </body>
<script>
    document.body.className = document.body.className.replace('no-js','');
</script>
```

Now you can extend this method to make as many styling changes you want based on this condition.

```
.no-js .xyz {
    display: none;
}
```